# jQuery not runned when page is loaded through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm working on this site, where I need to load pages using Javascript, since the original page can't refresh. After some googling, I found the following:

```
var loadedobjects = ""
var rootdomain = "http://" + window.location.hostname

function load(url) {
    var page_request = false
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    } else return false
    page_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        loadpage(page_request)
    }
    page_request.open('GET', '/pages/' + url + '.tpl', true);
    page_request.send(null);
}

function loadpage(page_request) {
    if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1)) {
        document.getElementById('MainContent').innerHTML = page_request.responseText;
    }
}

function loadobjs() {
    if (!document.getElementById) return
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var file = arguments[i]
        var fileref = ""
        if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file) == -1) {
            if (file.indexOf(".js") != -1) {
                fileref = document.createElement('script')
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
            } else if (file.indexOf(".css") != -1) {
                fileref = document.createElement("link")
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
            }
        }
        if (fileref != "") {
            document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
            loadedobjects += file + " "
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I've been using to load pages so far.

Now, when I have a page using JQuery. It does execute when I visit the page itself, So just the plain page at `/pages/pagename.tpl`. My jQuery runs perfectly. But when I click the page in my normal website, so through the Javascript it doesn't run.

Just to make sure, I coded the JQuery into the page itself, but it doesn't change anything.

Here's the page:

```
<div id="shoutContainer">
    <label for="shout">Shout</label>
    <textarea name="shout" rows="5" id="shout" placeholder="Jouw shout"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="requestContainer">
    <label for="artiest">De artiest</label>
    <input type="text" name="artiest" id="artiest" placeholder="De artiest">
    <label for="titel">De titel/label>
        <input type="text" name="titel" id="titel" placeholder="De titel"> </div>
</form>
</div>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#soortInstuur").change(update);
    });

    function update() {
        var val = $("#soortInstuur option:selected").val();
        if (val == 'shout') {
            $("#requestContainer").fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function() {
                $("#shoutContainer").fadeIn('slow');
            });
        } else if (val == 'request') {
            $("#shoutContainer").fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function() {
                $("#requestContainer").fadeIn('slow');
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

The `#requestContainer` is hidden though a external CSS file.

How is it, that this jQuery wont run? Do I need a different method to load pages?

Comment: JavaScript is not executed when set with innerHTML. Since you are using jQuery, why are you not using jQuery to make the Ajax call and set the html? It has stuff built in to handle the JavaScript.

Comment: Could it be something with the source of the jQuery?  Since the associated folders don't load with the page.  Can you add a web reference to hosted jQuery to that page instead?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by switching to AJAX.

Thanks for the help.